# How to exclude a specific format file in my find command?

Tags: shell

I am trying to compress files which have file extension .csv and *.log*, I dont want to compress files which are already compressed and are in .gz format. How do I exclude these .gz files in my find so it doesnt do zipping twice or end up throwing up an error. Below is the find command I tried to exclude files which are in .gz format but this doesnt work.

`find ${dir_name}  -type f \( -name "*.csv"  -o -name "*.log" \) ! -name "*.gz" -mtime +${LOG_COMPRESS}  ! -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION}  -exec gzip {} \;`

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what "this doesn't work" means?

Comment: My find gives me all the .csv and .log files and compresses it. there are some files with the following format test.log.09-09-2021.gz. How do i exclude this type of file in my find command as this is already compressed?

Comment: `\( -name "*.csv"  -o -name "*.log" \)` already excludes every other extension.

Comment: it excludes other extension but i have log files with format -->test.log.01-01-2021.,  im not able to compress files with this format.

Comment: So you need patterns that require `.log` or `.csv` to be at the *end* of the filename.